# Should I include phonegap.js or cordova-3.0.0.js or both in a Phonegap 3.0 app?

Tags: javascript, cordova, documentation

I have just started looking at Phonegap 3.0. If I create a new app skeleton using the command-line interface, I get an index.html file with phonegap.js included. On the other hand, all the examples in the [API reference in the documentation](http://docs.phonegap.com/en/3.0.0rc1/cordova_media_media.md.html#media.play) have cordova-3.0.0.js included instead.

Which one is the right one? Are they interchangeable? Do I need both?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need to add Cordova-3.0.0.js file if you already have Phonegap.js file included with your index.html. Just go ahead. That should do!

Comment: Verified - works fine! :-)